# I don't know what to associate the [associative] tag with

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

The [associative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/associative) tag has multiple meanings, lacks a tag wiki, and the excerpt does not help to clarify its use:

> This tag is used mostly regarding associative arrays (but better use tag "associative-array" for that) and sometimes in the mathematic sense of tag "associativity", the associative property of binary operations.

Looking over some of the 390 or so questions, it looks like many of them can just be retagged with the suggested [associative-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/associative-array) or [associativity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/associativity) tags.  I'm not sure what, exactly, "associative" in a tag is supposed to represent.

Should the existing questions be retagged where appropriate, possibly leaving some with this tag (and give it a better wiki and better excerpt)?  Or should we burninate the tag completely?